# JPOS Message header length and message body length mismatch

Tags: iso8583, jpos, openiso8583.net

Would like to check if there is an way to validate resolve the services for jpos if the message header indicate the length as 100 however the sent length is 99? Currently when i received the message from my client end it would required to restart if not the sequence message would fail.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Such a message is malformed an should be rejected. It expect most operators would flag this because its an indication of a major software fault somewhere along the line.

Comment: Perhaps your link sends a message trailer (typically an ETX character).

Comment: Yes, i would think so. Is the message trailer method is it a common practice? What are usually the standards of resolving this issue?